# How to batch fetch child-properites from a list of items?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have a search-method which returns multiple items, each with several child-properties with references to other tables.
For the child-property that is a collection everything works as I want it to but how can I do the same for the one-to-one children?

Here is some stubs and some of the code I tried:

```
public class Request {
    //HasMany(x => x.Examinations).Access.CamelCaseField().Cascade.All().BatchSize(100);
    public virtual IList<Examination> Examinations;

    //References(x => x.Creator, "rem_creator_userid");
    public virtual User Creator { get; private set; }
}

public class RepositoryExample {

    // This search will ask one nice-looking query to the database fetchning all the
    // requests
    // Then it will ask ONE query fetching the Examinations from the database
    // Then it will ask N+1 questions fetching Creator from all Requests
    public IList<Request> Search1(ListRequestSearchConditions searchConditions) {
        var query =
            from request in Session.Query<Request>()
            from exam in request.Examinations
            where
                searchConditions.Units.Contains(request.ReferralSource) &&
                exam.Status.HasValue &&
                exam.Status.Value >= ExaminationStatus.Value.RequestSubmitted &&
                request.PatientId != null
            select request;

        return query
            .Skip((searchConditions.Page - 1) * searchConditions.PageSize)
            .Take(searchConditions.PageSize)
            .ToList();
    }

    // This search with ask one slow join-query fetching everything from the database
    public IList<Request> Search2(ListRequestSearchConditions searchConditions) {
            Examination examinationAlias = null;

        return Session.QueryOver<Request>()
            .WhereRestrictionOn(request => request.ReferralSource).IsIn(searchConditions.Units)
            .Where(request => request.PatientId != null)
            .JoinAlias(request => request.Examinations, () => examinationAlias)
            .Where(() => examinationAlias.Status.Value != null)
            .Where(() => examinationAlias.Status.Value >= ExaminationStatus.Value.RequestSubmitted)
            .Skip((searchConditions.Page - 1) * searchConditions.PageSize)
            .Take(searchConditions.PageSize)
            .ToList();
    }

    // This search will first ask ONE query joining Request with Examinations
    // Then it will ask ONE query fetching the Examinations from the database
    // Then it will ask N+1 queries fetching Creator from all Requests
    public IList<Request> Search3(ListRequestSearchConditions searchConditions) {
            Examination examinationAlias = null;

        return Session.QueryOver<Request>()
            .WhereRestrictionOn(request => request.ReferralSource).IsIn(searchConditions.Units)
            .Where(request => request.PatientId != null)
            .JoinAlias(request => request.Examinations, () => examinationAlias)
            .Where(() => examinationAlias.Status.Value != null)
            .Where(() => examinationAlias.Status.Value >= ExaminationStatus.Value.RequestSubmitted)
            .Fetch(request => request.Examinations).Lazy
            .Fetch(request => examinationAlias.ExaminationType).Lazy;
            .Skip((searchConditions.Page - 1) * searchConditions.PageSize)
            .Take(searchConditions.PageSize)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

I hope that is possible to do this in 3 queries, one fetching the list of Requests, one fetching the Examinations and one fetching the Creators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have it in one single query (using `Fetch`/`ThenFetch` in LINQ) and use batching instead, you have to specify it at `Creator` mapping level. Batch size can't be defined at query level.

In Fluent NHibernate you can just add `BatchSize(100)` in your `Creator` mapping.

Comment: BatchSize() is not available for one-to-one-mappings which Creator is so if there is not a trick somewhere I cannot use that.

Comment: Add it on Creator entity level, not on relation level.

Comment: Thanks alot, was not aware that you could set batch-size on entity level!

Answer (score 0):

all in one roundtrip

```
// determine the requests
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Request>()
    .WhereRestrictionOn(request => request.ReferralSource).IsIn(searchConditions.Units)
    .Where(request => request.PatientId != null)
    .JoinQueryOver(request => request.Examinations)
    .Where(examination => examination.Status.Value != null)
    .Where(examination => examinationAlias.Status.Value >= ExaminationStatus.Value.RequestSubmitted)
    .Skip((searchConditions.Page - 1) * searchConditions.PageSize)
    .Take(searchConditions.PageSize)
    .Select(r => r.Id);

// load the requests with eagerly fetching the associations
var results = Session.QueryOver<Request>()
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(request => request.Id).In(subquery)
    .Fetch(request => request.Creator).Eager
    .Fetch(request => request.Examinations).Eager
    .ToList();
```